# Como eu posso usar o pip numa versão do python instalada pelo pyenv?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pygame

Eu instalei a versão 3.6.0rc2 no pyenv e realmente preciso do pygame nesta versão. Eu tentei usar `sudo pip uninstall pygame` e `sudo pip install pygame` e também tentei `sudo pip3 uninstall pygame` e `sudo pip3 install pygame`. Mas o pip e o pip3 só instalam o pygame no python3.5 e o 2.7, mas quando eu dou `pip -V` aparece:

> pip 9.0.1 from /home/rodrigo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0rc2/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Aparentemente tudo certinho mas não instala nada no python 3.6.0.

E eu não quero instalar o python 3.6 por outra coisa além do pyenv.

Answer (score 0):

O `pip` assim como a linguagem *Python* é bem especifico com as versões. Quando se vai iniciar o terminal *Python* temos:

```
python
python2
python2.6
python2.7
python3
python3.4
python3.5
...
```

Com o `pip` é a mesma coisa. O seu `pip3` por padrão deve estar configurado para o *Python3.5*, então use o `pip` do *Python3.6*

```
sudo pip3.6 install pygame
```

## Configurar `path` com `/usr/local/` para `su` e `sudo`

Edite o arquivo /etc/profile (use nano, vi, vim ou joe).

Acrescente o código na ultima linha do arquivo:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games/bin"
```

Esse `path`, já configura todos os diretórios que possuem os binários para todos os usuários, assim funcionando tanto para login com o `su` e `sudo`.

Comment: O path do root e do usuario não são diferentes(tentei dar sudo echo $PATH, caso eu tenha feito uma bobeira me corrija), mas o pip esta do /usr/local/bin, o que eu faço ?

Comment: Acrescentei como configurar o `PATH` do linux, é o `PATH` que eu uso, Graças a ele nunca tive problemas em não encontrar algum comando com qualquer usuário.

Comment: Ok eu fiz isso e o sudo continua sem reconhecer o pip3.6

Comment: faz o login direto como root apartir do modo terminal

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com os comentários esta usando o gnu/linux, segunda a estrutura FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard)  o local **/usr/bin/**  contém apenas arquivos não essenciais (que não são necessários para que o sistema funcione ou para a sua recuperação). ou seja não precisa ser root para acessar.

instalando :

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-setuptools python3-pkg-resources \
python3-pip python3-dev libffi-dev build-essential git

 pip install virtualenv

 pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

O python fica nesse local:

```
/usr/bin$ py
py3clean          pydoc2.7          pygettext3        python3
py3compile        pydoc3            pygettext3.8      python3.8
py3versions       pydoc3.8          pygettext3.9      python3.8-config
pyclean           pydoc3.9          pyjwt3            python3.9
pycompile         pygettext2        python2           python3-config
pydoc2            pygettext2.7      python2.7         pyversions
```

então caso queira usar o python 2 ou 3..
basta digitar o caminho certo com a versão que precisa:
**/usr/bin/python2.7**

Se o objetivo é padronizar uma versão para o uso  em um ambiente virtual, tente especificar o  **bashrc** para executa sempre que  iniciar.

configurando, na ultima linha :

```
:~$ cat .bashrc


export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python_versao_atual #usar essa versão
export WORKON_HOME=~/.vitualenvs # no ambiente
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh # gestor de ambiente
```

Eu considero o virtualenv facil de usar e criar ambientes para versões diferentes do python.

para criar ambientes:

```
 mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7  ambiente27
```

para usar a versão criada

```
workon ambiente27
```

o local onde fica as versões criadas é:

```
:~$ ls .vitualenvs/
```

Pelo que escreveu esta querendo usar o python **"3.6.0rc2"** Essa sigla RC2 significa  release candidate um candidato que esta na segunda vez de ser candidato a lançamento. não é uma versão final apenas um candidato.

Pode instalar essa versão se tem confiança no proposito dela, ela ficara em /usr/bin

A idéia é instalar uma versão do python atual e usar um gerenciador de ambiente virtual. Caso queira usar uma versão antiga só instalar e usar o virtualenv para gerencia-los seja a versão que queira.

Se isso não ajuda-lo, só informar novamente o resultado